Compressed helical spring powering an early stage of rocket
We take a (ball point pen ink tube) and (press release/retract spring) as a model for storing potential energy (PE). The ink tube can be projected up by the spring when kept free.
Is it possible to design a humongous but lightweight helical spring storing torsional PE and to deliver controlled release thrust in order to eliminate first/early stage of a launch vehicle? Some sort of a helical slingshot? The spring is to be made with carbon or Kevlar material so it has stored energy per unit mass in an earth bound experiment.
Preliminary energy calculations and dynamics indicate a feasibility.
Energy saving would be considerable as compression spring is easily loaded by power screws driven by electric motors.
Thanks for all comments.

I would recommend to check your preliminary energy calculations and dynamics very carefully, something must be wrong

Thanks for your concern. I had envisaged even using controlled negator springs to be part contributor at least for boost phase as ground based equipment cuts down cost of launching stages.  For the time being the question may be closed for considering a full dynamics model.

What you describe is similar in principle to an aircraft carrier catapult. These can accelerate an airplane up to 150kn which is a significant proportion of its cruise speed (600kn)
To have a proportionate effect on an orbital launch, the rocket stack would need to be accelerated to about Mach 1.3, requiring a spring several kilometers long to keep the g-force below 4 and avoid violating maxQ limits.
A helical spring's force increases linearly with compression (Hook's Law) so your astronauts are in for an unpleasant maxG at release, the opposite of what a rocket provides.
An aircraft catapult avoids Hooks law by providing constant acceleration with a steam cylinder.
I have experimented with ball point springs and refills. If scaled to launch vehicle size, the rocket catapult spring would land in the Bahamas. And that's just the first bounce.

"that's just the first bounce" - most terrifying sentence regarding springs I've ever heard. +1

@controlgroup ... I've dealt with compressed suspension springs working on cars. I'm terrified of them !!!

Not that it really matters, but an orbital rocket needs to reach Mach 23ish, so a boost in proportion to that provided by an aircraft catapult would be on the order of Mach 5 or 6.

The initial goal of a rocket (launching from Earth) is to gain altitude without increasing speed too quickly. This is because it's still well within the thick part of Earth's atmosphere, and going too fast will increase your dynamic pressure - if you go too fast, the vehicle will be ripped apart by the atmosphere. Many rocket first stages are actually throttled down as they approach the end of the first stage burn in part so that the maximum pressure - Max Q, as it's called in mission planning - will be lower.
This is a major problem for a launch system that is stuck on the surface, because it doesn't have the option a rocket does of providing a (relatively) slow acceleration over time. It has to provide its acceleration upfront, while the vehicle is mired in the thickest part of the atmosphere. That means that the vehicle will need to be much sturdier to survive the dynamic pressures developed, much more total energy will be expended because much of it is lost to drag, and the peak acceleration will be much higher (because of the need to impart all of this velocity before it leaves the launch mechanism) which would be deadly to crew and dangerous to cargo and the vehicle. (Reducing peak acceleration is the other major reason to throttle down a first stage.)
On a body without a significant atmosphere - the Moon, for instance - a spring (or railgun or steam catapult or whatever) would be much more practical for a boost, because you don't have to worry about drag and pressure. But on Earth, these ideas are a non-starter.

All true, upvoted. But do separate the two times they throttle down. Max Q is much earlier in the first burn, somewhere around Mach 1 and 10-20 km when the air is still quite thick. So they first reduce thrust for a while to reduce the peak aerodynamic force on the nose (definition of max q) and then at the end of the burn to reduce the acceleration and hence force on the whole second stage, payload, people etc. Not all rockets need to do the second one, F9 doesn't (perhaps stage 2 is so heavy it's not necessary).

No.
Take for instance the Saturn V moon rocket. The fuel mass for the first stage was around 2076500 kilograms of  RP-1. With an energy density of around 28.1 mega joules per kilogram, that’s around 58.35 terajoules of energy stored in the fuel - almost fifteen kilotons of TNT’s worth.
The key part of a rocket is that you can expend this energy over time. If you do it all at once (e.g. with a spring, like you propose), then you would be releasing around fifteen kilotons of TNT all at once - of course, this would look roughly like a nuclear explosion.
Even if you could survive it, the air would slow the rocket down almost immediately. Getting to suborbital speed in the time it takes for the spring to expand would be catastrophic.

Springs do release their energy over a distance, rather than instantaneously. You’d just need a long enough spring … that also doesn’t just collapse under its own weight.

Haha, good luck. Also consider the necessity to control the spring on its way up (out?) away from the ground - any tilt would be catastrophic.
